# How do I add a song progress bar for soundmanager2 (inlineplayer)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, progress-bar, soundmanager2

I've just installed soundmanager2 on my website.  Since my site contains various mp3 links, I've opted to use sm2's inlineplayer solution, which seeks out mp3s on the page and replaces them with instances of the inline player.  The player is working now and I'd like to add a progress bar.

I found a sm2 solution for a progress bar at the link below, but the solution is not working for me, for some reason.  The bar appears but no progress is shown: [How to add a song progress bar in SoundManager2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273444/how-to-add-a-song-progress-bar-in-soundmanager2)

You can see the player with the progress bar, that's not working, here: http://goo.gl/oD90Oj/.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My sm2 call:

```
var inlinePlayer = null;

soundManager.setup({
    // disable or enable debug output
    debugMode: false,
    // use HTML5 audio for MP3/MP4, if available
    preferFlash: false,
    useFlashBlock: true,
    waitForWindowLoad: true,
    // path to directory containing SM2 SWF
    url: '../js/soundmanagerv2/swf/',
    // optional: enable MPEG-4/AAC support (requires flash 9)
    flashVersion: 9
});

// ----

soundManager.onready(function() {
    // soundManager.createSound() etc. may now be called
    inlinePlayer = new InlinePlayer();
});

// Setup progress bar width
soundManager.whileplaying(function() {
    jQuery(".progBar").css('width', ((this.position/this.duration) * 100) + '%');
});
// Reset progress bar after play
soundManager.onfinish(function() {
    jQuery(".progBar").css('width', '0');
});
```

My CSS:

```
/* Style Progress Bar */
.progBarWrap {
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.progBar {
    width: 0;
    background-color: #222;
    height:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

soundManager does not have a function named `whileplaying` you need to use `soundManager.createSound` with `whileplaying` options as it is shown in the SO answer you gave.

alternatively as you know start/stop time and duration of course you can manually use JS [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval). I am pretty sure this is what whileplaying method doing behind scenes.

EDIT: `soundManager` provides an event called `whileplaying` but it not a function of `soundManager`. The `whileplaying` is function of instance of the sound object you created with `soundManager`. I hope that makes sense.

so if you want to use `whileplaying` you can either use  createSound method which will attach the event to sound object or get the instance of sound and use `sound.play` method with options just check [the demo](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/api/#onposition-2) you have sent me. I think you are already calling this function or similar one when user clicks the play button.

```
//From the demo page as you can see s is sound.
s.play({
  whileplaying: function() {
    // demo only: show sound position while playing, for context
    soundManager._writeDebug('position = ' + this.position);
  },
  onfinish: function() {
    // when the sound finishes, play it once more to show that the listener does not fire.
    soundManager._writeDebug('Playing once more, onPosition() should not fire');
    this.play({
      onfinish: function() {
        soundManager._writeDebug('"' + this.id + '" finished.');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

EDIT For 2nd comment: Not sure when are you calling that `css`. Assuming you have succeeded to attach `whileplaying` event. The code tries to find player's progress bar but looks like the HTML structure different than yours. the below selector should the trick for you.

```
  $("a.sm2_link.sm2_playing") // finds the active (playing) link
      .closest("div.post-entry") // finds the parent element for both player and progress
      .find("div.progBar") //finally finds progress bar now you can change the width
      .css("width", /*YOUR CALCULATION HERE*/);
```

Theoretically you can just use `$("div.progBar")` for the page but finding relative to player has benefits in case you have multiple player in one page.

Comment: hmmm.  Thanks for the response.  However, I believe sm2 has the whileplaying() function built in.  It's exemplified on their website, here, under "demo 11": http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/api/

Comment: please check updated answer also in the demo 11 it uses sound.options not soundManager.

Comment: Good point!  Actually after your initial comment, I started looking for another solution and found one in jQuery.  However, I'm also having trouble implementing that one.  I'm not sure how to target the "#player" using the following code:  **$("#player > .progress-bar-container").css('width', ((this.bytesLoaded/this.bytesTotal) * 100) + '%'); $("#player > .progress-bar-container > .progress-bar").css('width', ((this.position/this.duration) * 100) + '%');**

Comment: I'm currently using the inlineplayer to grab my mp3 links and convert them into instances of the sm2 player.  My links are built as such: **<a href="song.mp3" class="sm2_link inline-playable" type="audio/mpeg">Song Title</a>**

Comment: I appreciate the answer but, unfortunately, I'm not sure how the player is being called.  I assume it's somewhere within the "inline-player" code itself.  As you can see from my original code, when the document is ready, a player can be called, but I'm not doing it.  It's already being done somewhere else within the demo code.